# Retrieve xml containing @ using SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have table called `Announcement` with a XML column called `XMLData`.

By using a SQL Server query, I try to retrieve value of `Currency` and `PriceValue`.

Sample XML:

```
<AmtPrice> 
    <PricValue Currency="USD">2.33</PricValue>
</AmtPrice>
```

My query:

```
select Announcement.XMLData.value('(/AmtPrice/PricValue[@Currency="USD"]/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') As PriceValue
```

Manage to get `PriceValue` by using the above query. My problem is, how to get `Currency` value?

Comment: 1. How the output should look like? 2. You are already filtering by currency code, so it should be known at the time the query runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query allows for multiple `PricValue` nodes and selects the first one which has the USD currency. If know you have only one `PricValue` nodes or if you want the select the first `PricValue` nodes (regardless of currency), you could use something like this:

```
SELECT XMLData.value('(/AmtPrice/PricValue)[1]', 'NUMERIC(10,2)') As PriceValue,
       XMLData.value('(/AmtPrice/PricValue/@Currency)[1]', 'CHAR(3)') As Currency
FROM Announcement
```

I have used specific data types instead of `nvarchar(max)` for better performance. If the price is not numeric or is larger than what fits in a `NUMERIC(10),2` you would get an error. If it has more decimals they will be silently rounded. If the currency is longer than 3 characters it will be silently truncated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT 
    Announcement.XMLData.value('(/AmtPrice/PricValue/@Currency)[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)') As Currency,
    Announcement.XMLData.value('(/AmtPrice/PricValue[@Currency="USD"])[1]', 'DECIMAL(18,2)') As PriceValue
```

By specifying `@Currency` in the XPath, you're reading out the attribute value of   the `Currency` attribute.

I would also **strongly** recommend to use **the most appropriate** datatype when converting the values - and using `NVARCHAR(MAX)` for a value of `2.33` doesn't seem very appropriate - use a `DECIMAL(p,s)` type for that instead.